# Python | Dash | Bootstarp - Dynamically change theme for Dark Mode

Tags: python, css, themes, plotly-dash, darkmode

I am new to bootstrap and I was trying to figure out how to load a theme to dynamically change the css theme on Dash App.

Ideally I want to give a toggle button to switch between Light(Cerulean) and Dark mode(Darkly).

My current app setting looks like this,

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width"}])
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the ThemeSwitchAIO component, https://hellodash.pythonanywhere.com/theme_change_components